Children's chapter book about a lonely girl whose new best friend is actually her de-aged mother
A lonely girl engages a mysterious service that promises to provide her with the perfect best friend. In no time, she meets a friendly young girl her age to befriend. Everything seems perfect until she realizes where her new friend came from - the service de-aged her mother into a girl her age!
More detailed plot beats, as best I can recall:

The main character is an average young girl (elementary-age?) who is lonely and doesn't have a best friend (perhaps she has no friends at all?). She lives with her mother (I don't recall if her father is in the picture) who she doesn't have the best relationship with.

Somehow she learns about and comes into contact with some sort of shady service that promises a "perfect" best friend for anyone, despite some misgivings she signs up.

Returning home, she finds two things: her mother is not home, there is a note or letter (?) saying that she has had to take an unexpected trip and not to worry. There is also a mess in the kitchen - things are scattered about as if dropped, and there is a strange dark sticky substance splattered on the floor. She cleans up, including wiping up the spills and throwing away the dirty paper towels.

Almost immediately afterwards, she encounters a young girl her age outside. The new girl doesn't know how she got there and briefly has trouble remembering her name. The two get along and become fast friends - this girl is the promised "best friend".

As time passes the protagonist grows concerned about her mother, who hasn't been seen or heard from since before the new friend showed up. Somehow the girl comes to a realization - her new best friend is actually her mother, who has been de-aged to a child! I don't recall what exactly triggers this realization but I think part of the reveal is that the girl is using a diminutive version of her mom's name (e.g., mom is Elizabeth and girl is Lizzie).

Somehow she (maybe aided by someone else?) returns to the shady service and confronts them. As some sort of revenge the machine/process is turned on one of the men running things and he becomes a little boy (in a humorous scene, he petulantly demands a beer when offered ice cream by one of his former co-conspirators who clearly doesn't know how to talk to a child). They are able to reverse the process on her mother, who is at home, but they are alarmed to hear she mopped up and discarded the substance - it was protein (or some similar form of nutrients/energy) displaced during the transformation to a smaller body with less mass. She races home to find her mother returning to her proper age - without the original protein, she has instead absorbed nearby food to fuel the transformation. Similarly to when she first appeared as a girl, she is somewhat dazed and does not seem to remember the past few days - but in a Freaky Friday-esque conclusion mother and daughter have a renewed appreciation and love for each other.


Details about the book itself:

I read this book in the early 00s, in grade school (during independent reading, it was not assigned). The book wasn't new, it was part of my teacher's library collection, so it may have been from the 90s or 80s.

The tone is pretty light, it's meant to be a fun mystery-adventure rather than something scary like ''Goosebumps'' or a thrilling sci-fi.

It was a chapter book, but rather brief and geared towards younger readers. I remember it having that sort of Apple Paperback look, a slim paperback volume with an illustrated cover framed by a solid color... I'm pretty sure it wasn't part of a series. The book was narrated in third-person, limited to the main character's perspective.

The cover illustration was a mostly-realistic painting, as common among paperbacks of the era. It depicted the de-aging scene: a young girl 'shrinking' down, dressed in suddenly-too-baggy adult clothes, while the papers and such that she had been holding fluttered about her. I remember being a little annoyed by this after reading - partially because this scene is not depicted in the book (the protagonist does not see this happen) and because the narrative means for it to be a surprise reveal that the new girl is in fact a de-aged adult.



Welcome ApeelingPotate. Nice first question! Take a look at our [tour] and visit the [help] pages to get more information on this site and how it works.
